# Grid for coldfusion with popup editor - similar to Telerik RAD Grid for ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server-2008, datagrid, editor, coldfusion-9, cfquery

I am looking for a grid solution that works in Coldfusion that is similar to Telerik RAD Grid for ASP.NET with a popup editor. In addition to this is must be able to connect to SQL or be modified with CFQuery tags. Your help is appreciated, I have been looking for days.

I have looked at FlexiGrid and JQGrid, neither solution was able to connect to a DB or piggyback a CFQuery, unless I missed something (I'm still new at Coldfusion/javascript/JQuery, I am a .NET guy).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CFGrid?
You would have to write your own popup editor though.
adobe coldfusion reference: [Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a01.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-72e0)

```
<cfform name="form01"> 
 <cfgrid format="html" name="grid01" pagesize=5 sort=true 
        bind="cfc:places.getData({cfgridpage},{cfgridpagesize}, 
        {cfgridsortcolumn},{cfgridsortdirection})"> 
    <cfgridcolumn name="Emp_ID" display=true header="eid" /> 
    <cfgridcolumn name="FirstName" display=true header="Name"/> 
    <cfgridcolumn name="Email" display=true header="Email" />  
 </cfgrid> 
</cfform>
```

Comment: I have, the issue there is that the grid doesn't update instantly like an AJAX style grid would. I am looking at DataTables but that script doesn't support SQL/CFQuery strings, only JSON (which I don't know and have been having trouble understanding).

Comment: kkick, JSON is well worth getting your head around if you want to do  AJAX.  Not all that hard.. spend an hour doing a tut on it and you would be good to go.